'Android SDK "Android API 29 Platform" is not found on the disk or corrupted.' in Android Studio while using Flutter
While using flutter there is this constant pop up saying 'Android SDK "Android API 29 Platform" is not found on the disk or corrupted.' when I press configure it doesn't work with any of the available options and bugs afterwards.
I tried downloading sdk from the sdk manager and changing it in the project structure and i
tried a solution from a similar post but didn't get what are the purple folders mentioned there. Here is the accepted solution there:
Settings > Language & frameworks > Android SDK > select Android 10.0 (API Level 29), then click OK.
then go to file > project structure
In project select sdk Android API 33
in modules select the purple folders and select Module SDK: Android 33.
